# How to convert a date string from 'dd//mm/yy' to 'mm/dd/yy' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, function, date

I am using a library to calculate the age from date of birth. I am taking date of birth as an input which is in the format of dd/mm/yy but the library that calculated the age accepts it in the format of mm/dd/yy. One solution to this is to change the date selector format in the application but I dont want to do that since it gets confusing.

I searched the solution on stackoverflow but couldnt find the solution here- [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: You should search [\[javascript\] reformat date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reformat+date). :-) There is always `'31/12/2021'.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/g, '$2/$1/$3')`.

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
var yourDate = "10/12/2021";
var arrayOfDate = yourDate.split("/");
console.log([arrayOfDate[1], arrayOfDate[0], arrayOfDate[2]].join('/'));
```

Comment: thanks for the solution problem solved! :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it with `/` and then use [`destructure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it and get the desired result as:

```
const result = `${mm}/${dd}/${yy}`;
```

```js
var oldDate = "10/12/21";
var [dd, mm, yy] = oldDate.split("/");
const newDate = `${mm}/${dd}/${yy}`;
console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: const newDate = `${mm}/${dd}/${yyyy.split(0,2)[1]}`;                    to get mm/dd//yy format

Comment: No need for that, Since OP want to convert `dd/mm/yy` to `mm/dd/yy`